# retuning a promise using async await pattern with some delay

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to return some test data from a method that calls a rest api. To simulate the rest api call, I am adding some delay to return a promise using async-await pattern, but its not working as expected.

My understanding of async-await pattern in JavaScript is that any value returned from an async function is returned as a promise, so the value 100 should be returned as a promise by the function and therefore the last statement using `.then` should show 100, but it's not.

**Question**
What is wrong with the code snippet below which is causing the alert in last line of code to show `undefined` rather than 100?

```js
async function f() {

  function delayedResponse() {
    setTimeout(function() { return 100}, 5000);
  }
  return await delayedResponse();

}

f().then(alert); // 100
```

Comment: `delayedResponse` doesn't return anything -> `undefined`

Comment: If there's no explicit `Promise` the return value will be automatically wrapped in a `Promise`. If you want to "return" something from the `setTimeout` callback you have to use a `Promise` and resolve it in the callback.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. I have to use Promise object. I was under the impression that I could just use async await without Promise but its clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't return anything in your `delayedResponse` so it's resulted in `undefined`.

Instead, in order to achieve what you expect - you can create a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) explicitly and resolve a value using timeout;

```js
async function f() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(100)}, 5000);
  }); 
}

f().then(alert); // 100
```

Comment: FYI, you can do `setTimeout(resolve, 5000, 100);` instead of declaring the separate callback function for `setTimeout(function() { resolve(100)}, 5000);`.

Comment: @jfriend00 for sure!

Answer (score 1):

#### NodeJS 14.x or Browser API

```
async function delay(msecs: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msecs));
}
```

#### NodeJS 16.x or later

```
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises";
const result = await setTimeout(msecs, 'somevalue')
```

Note that the order of the `setTimeout()` arguments has changed!
The old `setTimeout()` is defined unless you import from "timers/promises".

References

- [Node 16 - Timers Promises API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api)